# Div rolling on top of another Div

Tags: html, css

How do I make a div roll on top of another div while scrolling? I tried using `z-index` but doesn't seem to work the code as I want. Please look at the images below.

[image]
[image]

I want the green div to be on top of the "App Name Here" div (to cover it), and not below it. **How should I do that?** Here is the code I'm using

HTML

```html
    <div class="header">
        <div>
            <h1><span style="color: rgb(133, 13, 13);">App Name </span><span style="color: rgb(39, 161, 15);">Here</span></h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box1">
        <header>
            <h2 style="text-align: center;margin-bottom:15px;font-family:cursive;">Info.</h2>
        </header>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply .....
        </p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body{
            background-image: url("social_media_background_small.jpg");
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .box1 {
            height: 90vh;
            background-color: aquamarine;
            z-index: 99;
            border-radius: 12px;
            padding: 2rem;
        }
        .box1 p{
            text-align: justify;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: rgb(27, 21, 21);
            opacity: 0.75;
            height: 60vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
        }
        .header div{
            z-index: 0;
        }

        .header div h1 {
            font-size: 3rem;
            z-index: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `position` the `box1` element:

```
        .box1 {
            position: relative;
            height: 90vh;
            background-color: aquamarine;
            z-index: 99;
            border-radius: 12px;
            padding: 2rem;
        }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context